# preg_match to find number of elements starting with id

Tags: php, regex

Can you please tell me how to use preg_match in php to find the number of elements in an html starting with a particular id.

```
<div id="test_1"></div>   
<div id="test_2"></div>
<div id="test_3"></div>
```

find the number of elements starting with id="test_". So in the above example I should get 3
Also get the second parameter in the form of an array
So 
    Arr[0] = 1; 
    Arr[1] = 2; 
    Arr[2] = 3;

Can anyone please tell me how the above can be done.

Comment: Don't use regex for this! Use a HTML parser and then either a selector such as `[id="test_*"]` or XPath or whatever the library you are using provides you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '<div id="test_1"></div><div id="test_2"></div><div id="test_3"></div>';
if ( preg_match_all( '/test_([0-9]+)/', $str, $matches ) )
{
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way:

```
$regex = '~id="test_\K[^"]~';
$number_of_matches = preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
if ($number_of_matches) print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Results**

- `$number_of_matches` is 3
- `$matches[0]` is an array with the three matches: `(1,2,3)`, i.e. `$matches[0][0]` is 1, `$matches[0][1]` is 2, `$matches[0][2]` is 3.